# How to verify that the table has been correctly sorted in Codeception?

Tags: codeception

How can I test that the order of the rows in an HTML table is correct, after "clicking" table column caption to sort the table?

Comment: I only found this unanswered topic: http://phptest.club/t/how-to-check-search-and-sort-function-in-codeception/496

Comment: You can try this:
1. Get the values in the table (before sort)
2. Store them in an array. (Let's call it Array A)
3. Use sort() function (if you're running php)
4. Sort the table.
5. Get the values in the table and store them in a different array. (Array B)
6. Compare the Arrays A & B

Comment: Good idea. But how would I get the values of an html table Column into PHP array? Would you write a full answer below?

Answer (score 0):

It should be something like this:

*Assuming that the table has only 1 column

```
$elements = $this->elements($this->using('xpath')->value("//div[@id='row']/div")); //identifying row element
$rows = count($elements); //count the number of rows

$unsortedrow = [];
$unsortedrows = []


for($count=0;$count<$rows;$count++){    // Get all values in Unsorted table

    $unsortedrow[$count] = $I->grabTextFrom('//div[@id='main_body']/div/div['.$count.']/div/strong'); // Get text from row
    array_push($unsortedrows, $unsortedrow[$count]); // push the value of row N to rows array

}
```

Note: `$this->elements()` and `count()` are proven working in selenium 2 but I don't know if it also does in codeception, according to some of the articles i've read `seeNumberOfElements` is the alternative for that.